# How to merge two CSV or Excel files

Tags: excel, csv

I want to merge two files, format is csv or excel, below are the condition

1. both the files has logically same data (like name, age, address etc).
2. file may have different columns name.(like one file has name field as "Your Name" other one just "Name")
3. Order of columns may be different

Please  share  your idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

One possible method:

1. Write a data structure for the shared fields expected in the final output.
2. Write a function to read file A into a slice of data structure in step 1.
3. Write a function to read file B into a slice of data structure in step 1.
4. Combine the resultant slices of steps 2 and 3.
5. Write a function to write the resultant slice from step 4 into the output file.